# Extracting Head nouns

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I wonder how we can extract Head Nouns?  I used a Constituency parser that did not work but I guess I have to use a dependency parser. I ran this demo code but it gives me a wrong answer.

```
public class dependencydemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    PrintWriter out;
    if (args.length > 1) {
      out = new PrintWriter(args[1]);
    } else {
      out = new PrintWriter(System.out);
    }



    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP();
    Annotation annotation;
    if (args.length > 0) {
      annotation = new       ` 
 Annotation(IOUtils.slurpFileNoExceptions(args[0]));`
    } else {
      annotation = new Annotation("Yesterday, I went to the Dallas `Country Club to play 25 cent Bingo.  While I was there I talked to my `friend Jim and we both agree that those people in Washington are `destroying our economy.");`
    }

    pipeline.annotate(annotation);
    pipeline.prettyPrint(annotation, out);


    List<CoreMap> sentences = `annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);`
    if (sentences != null && sentences.size() > 0) {
      CoreMap sentence = sentences.get(0);
      Tree tree = `sentence.get(TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation.class);`
     // out.println();
    //  out.println("The first sentence parsed is:");
      tree.pennPrint(out);
    }
   }
```

Output:

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (NP-TMP (NN Yesterday))
    (, ,)
    (NP (PRP I))
    (VP (VBD went)
      (PP (TO to)
        (NP (DT the) (NNP Dallas) (NNP Country) (NNP Club)))
      (S
        (VP (TO to)
          (VP (VB play)
            (S
              (NP (CD 25) (NN cent))
              (NP (NNP Bingo)))))))
    (. .)))
```

Dependencies:

```
root(ROOT-0, went-4)
tmod(went-4, Yesterday-1)
nsubj(went-4, I-3)
det(Club-9, the-6)
nn(Club-9, Dallas-7)
nn(Club-9, Country-8)
prep_to(went-4, Club-9)
aux(play-11, to-10)
xcomp(went-4, play-11)
num(cent-13, 25-12)
nsubj(Bingo-14, cent-13)
xcomp(play-11, Bingo-14)
```

How can I extract Head-Nouns out of it? aside from it seems that the output is not correct.

Comment: What do you mean by "head noun"? Are you looking for the headwords of sentence constituents (only when they are nouns)? Or the subject of the sentence?

Comment: In the semantic tree the noun part of speech that has some childs for example in above example "club", "Bingo" are head-nouns.

Answer (score 1):

My impression from your explanation in your comment is that you want the head constituents of all noun phrases. This is very easy to do with CoreNLP.

1. First, find all noun phrases. You can do this with a simple Tregex pattern (see [Chris Manning's relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29189510/176075)).
2. You can use a CoreNLP "head finder" to select syntactic head constituents of the matched noun phrases. See e.g. the [`ModCollinsHeadFinder`](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/ModCollinsHeadFinder.java).

Demo code follows.

```
// Fetch a head finder.
HeadFinder hf = new PennTreebankLanguagePack().headFinder();

Tree myTree = ...
TregexPattern tPattern = TregexPattern.compile("NP");
TregexMatcher tMatcher = tPattern.matcher(myTree);
while (tMatcher.find()) {
  Tree nounPhrase = tMatcher.getMatch();

  Tree headConstituent = hf.determineHead(nounPhrase);
  System.out.println(headConstituent);
}
```

Comment: I run it but the answer is the following that obviously is not showing headnouns :(NN Yesterday)
(PRP I)
(NNP Club)
(NP (CD 25) (NN cent))
(NN cent)
(NNP Bingo)
(PRP I)
(NP (EX there))
(EX there)
(PRP I)
(NNP Jim)

Comment: I've used the following pattern using semgrexPattern that works in my example. Would you please tell me if it works generally? I check some time and worked... SemgrexPattern semgrex = SemgrexPattern.compile("[{pos:NNS}=A|{pos:NNP}=A|{pos:NN}=A] > !{pos:POS}=B");

Comment: Please update your question and give a more thorough description of what you've done so that we can help.